# Could not identify launch activity: Default Activity not found Error while Launching activity

Tags: android, android-studio

I am new in android studio and having this error when i try to run my app. i looked for solution but can't fix it. i am trying gmail login in my app.
i changed in build gradle

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.1.11'
```

to

```
     compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
```

error[image]

Manifest is as below

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
<application
    android:name=".MytestApp"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/logo"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
<meta-data
    android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
    android:value="@string/app_id" />
<provider
    android:name="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider"
    android:authorities="com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProvider572987599539975"
    android:exported="true" />
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="Home"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
</activity>
<activity
    android:name=".LoginActivity"
    android:label="Login">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity
    android:name=".SplashActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name">
</activity>
<activity android:name=".GoogleActivity"/>
<activity
    android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"                      android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
</manifest>
```

Build Gradle

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.bishnu.mylifemarkapp"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 24
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}
repositories {
mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.0'

compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
}
```

Comment: post your complete manifest as code not image

Comment: what error your're getting?

Comment: Try to Restart with this....File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart...

Comment: Have you created LoginActivity.java file in your src folder?

Comment: yes i do have LoginActivity.java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Close you `<application>` tag after declaring all activities. I could find that you closed it before declaring the activities.
From your image posted it is clear that `android:exported="true" />` you have closed the tag.

Answer (score 1):

Clean Project or rebuild project then run its run successfully. Basically its problem occur due to instant run. So you can disable  run for avoid this problem 
https://developer.android.com/studio/run/index.html

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have registered all activities inside manifest tag.
That's not correct, Add all activities inside Application Tag.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
    package="com.javatpoint.hello"  
    android:versionCode="1"  
    android:versionName="1.0" >  

    <uses-sdk  
        android:minSdkVersion="8"  
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />  

    <application  
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"  
        android:label="@string/app_name"  
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >  
        <activity  
            android:name=".MainActivity"  
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >  
            <intent-filter>  
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />  

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />  
            </intent-filter>  
        </activity>  
    </application>
```